# when I start any spring boot project java.net.MalformedURLException has been shown

Tags: spring-boot

when I start  any spring boot project  java.net.MalformedURLException has been shown What can I do with this exception?

this the messsege
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x665
jdk.internal.agent.AgentConfigurationError: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x665
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.startRemoteConnectorServer(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.management.agent/jdk.internal.agent.Agent.startAgent(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Service URL contains non-ASCII character 0x665
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL.(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.management.agent/sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.exportMBeanServer(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more

Comment: your question is similar to this one. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948507/spring-boot-error-exception-thrown-by-the-agent-java-net-malformedurlexcept?rq=1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot : Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948507/spring-boot-error-exception-thrown-by-the-agent-java-net-malformedurlexcept)

Answer (score 4):

For future seekers who are using Spring in IntelliJ :

I assume that you are not using a non-ascii character in your URLs, yet you are getting this message.

**JMX Agent** is enabled by default and if you have a non iso-8859 codepage (i.e. windows locale) you get this error.

[image: error picture with jms agent]

Set up your JMX and eliminate the usage of non-ascii characters (numbers maybe for a port!)

or

**Just disable it** if you do not want to use it (looks like you don't)

Goto **Edit Configuration** and Disable JMX Agent like below :

[image: disable JMX]

Re-run your project and it is working now :

[image: working picture]

For Eclipse users it shouldn't be different.

Note: you see the non-ascii characters in the following pictures too!!

Answer (score 0):

My windows locale was set to show numbers in non English format. Changing to English format fix the issue.

It seems that java can not start server on port `۸۰۸۰` only `8080` is accepted

Answer (score -1):

this error according to windows Unicode Utf-8 disable it.

[image: windows Unicode Utf-8]

Comment: Please instead of share a link add the resume of the instructions as asnswer and let the link as extra information.